# Removing index.php from URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know that there are a lot of similar posts (I went thru the most of them) but for some reason nothing helps removing index.php from URL.

**these:**

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/about
http://example.com/index.php/about
```

**should become:**

```
http://www.example.com/about
http://example.com/about
```

**I've run:** `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

**Config file:**

```
inanzzz@ubuntu:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled$ sudo nano 000-default.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Some of the solutions I tried:**

**1) [Link](http://dense13.com/blog/2012/10/29/removing-index-html-with-mod_rewrite-in-htaccess/)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**2) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059920/removing-index-html-from-url-and-adding-www-with-one-single-301-redirect)**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule . http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

**3) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

**4) [Link](http://simplemediacode.info/remove-index-html-andor-index-php-from-the-url/)**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**5) [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608366/remove-index-php-from-url-with-htaccess)** This return 500 Internal server error

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Why you don't use `RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]` for the fisrt part ?

Comment: @anubhava - 5th was yours anyway and this return 500 as well.

Comment: @inanzzz: Check Apache error.log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: @Croises: `RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+) /$1 [R=301,L]` will cause looping.

Comment: @anubhava - it is empty

Comment: That means you're not looking at correct error log file, every 500 error is written in error log with actual reason of 500

Comment: @anubhava - Sorry if I try to well understand... but with `index.php` it's the first, and without the second, I can't see where is the loop. The second change again with `index.php`, but with `[L]` don't use again this .htaccess ?

Comment: `L` only causes current loop to end in `mod_rewrite`, it doesn't mean not to use this rule again. Pls test it to see it causing looping.

Comment: I tried without problem. There must be anything else that escapes me. Thank you!